# python question for beginner provide the solution

Tags: python-3.x

Write a program to replace each odd elements of a list of integers
by its immediately available evenelement.
Eg: if the list contains:9 , 7 , 30 , 10 , 17 , 50 , 13
Resultant list: 30 , 30 , 30 , 10 , 50 ,50 , 13

Comment: I think this is not a platform to ask for the whole code, but I will give you some hints to solve this problem. 

 1. Map all the indexes which are even with their value.
 2. Create an auxiliary array and store the nearest element in it. Eg. If map is {4,10},{8,12} then store [10,10,10,10,10,10,12,12] like this.

Comment: Why does your result list end with `13`? And what exactly does "immediately available even element" mean? If the input is `4 2 13 11 9 3 8 5 3 9 1`, what should the output be?

Comment: @ekhumoro I think "immediately available even element" means: the even element within the list which has the closest index to "the odd element which needs to be replaced"  and which doesn't have a lower index than "the odd element which needs to be replaced". So your list would be converted to [4, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5, 3, 9, 1]. If there is no available even element then the value of "the odd element which needs to be replaced" doesn't change

Comment: @user17301834 Sure. But that assumes the OP has properly understood/reproduced the instructions they were given by their tutor, which is what I was trying to get at. I'm not interested in doing their homework for them.

Comment: @ekhumoro Fair enough